# Angular Cli is giving error while creating enw project

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I installed: npm install --save angular-cesium
When I create new project: ng new myapp   it gives the error:

```
CREATE drawangularcesium/src/app/app.component.ts (221 bytes)
CREATE drawangularcesium/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE drawangularcesium/e2e/protractor.conf.js (752 bytes)
CREATE drawangularcesium/e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json (213 bytes)
CREATE drawangularcesium/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (313 bytes)
CREATE drawangularcesium/e2e/src/app.po.ts (208 bytes)
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:362:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

Please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

I think you are creating your project in C:> . Try creating your project in some folder like C:\AnyFolder>